# Linux Container on Android

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, lxc

I have been looking into the video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpIFByNLM5U which shows the final results of running ICS and Jelly bean simultaneously on the emulator,

As they haven't provided any description how they did that, can anyone guide me through how they performed and what is their app on the android device responsible for doing?

Also, does someone know that where is the LXC image is stored which can be used to create similar duplicates on the device as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found following pdf very useful, Please go through it

http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/LXCBENCH_ALS2013-v1.00_0.pdf